# Drupal 7 displaying content issue

Tags: drupal-7

How to hide a specific field of basic page content type? Not from admin pannel Structure>content type>basic page> manage display.. I want to hide it in my page template then showing separatly so that i can customize it?

Answer (score 0):

In your template, you can use the [hide function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/hide/7) to prevent fields from being rendered.

Here's an exampled from the Garland theme's node template:

```
  <div class="content clearfix"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php
      // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
      hide($content['comments']);
      hide($content['links']);
      print render($content);
    ?>
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix">
    <?php if (!empty($content['links'])): ?>
      <div class="links"><?php print render($content['links']); ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanku @reallyxloco but i got the sol by using below code.......................  .`$body = field_get_items('node',$node, 'body');`